# how to properly include execute options when programmatically creating quarto code chunks?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, quarto

In order to streamline my workflow within my Quarto documents, I want to programmatically create some often used code chunks. However, I don't know how to properly include execute options. When I `cat` them, they, well, get `cat`ed into the final output instead of being treated as actual chunk options.

This is a minimal working example.
First code chunk works as expected. In the second one, `#| include: false\n` is interpreted as an ordinary string, and thus `do not print this either` is printed.

````
---
title: "programmatically generating code blocks with execute options"
format: html
---


```{r}
#| include: false
print("do not print this")
```

```{r, results='asis'}
cat("```{r}\n")
cat("#| include: false\n")
print("do not print this either")
cat("```\n")
cat("\n\n")
```
````

Any pointers? Thank you!

Comment: If you executing R code then why not use `if`?

Comment: Instead of what exactly? I want the code to be evaluated, just not printed (so maybe this is an unfortunate example). Also this is a general problem for me, it's not just about this specific execute option. I want to use eval, label, cache.extra, and custom created ones (dark/light mode switches)....

Comment: you can do cat("```{r, include=FALSE}\n") instead of using the quarto way of using the |# include: false

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Perhaps wrapping with `invisible`?